# Set conditions for pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm trying to do custom paginates on CakePHP, the thing is that I want to pass custom conditions, something like this:

```
$conditions['People'] = $this->People->find('all',
    array(
        'order' => array('People.id DESC'),
        'limit' => 16, 
        'order' => 'People.id DESC'
    )
);

$people = $this->paginate('People',$conditions);
```

That's basically all the code involving pagination, but it doesn't work, it throws that it doesn't find the column People...

I just want to do paginations with custom conditions, that is, I want to set the conditions beforehand, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved it, this is what I did:
First I declare the paginate, it can be empty if you want:

```
public $paginate = array('People'=>array(
        'limit' => 6,
        'order' => 'People.id DESC'
    ));
```

then, whenever I want to change something, I just do:

```
$this->paginate['People']['limit'] = 12;
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you take a look at the documentation?

According the documentation you should add conditions like this:

```
public function list_recipes() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%'),
        'limit' => 10
    );
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Recipe');
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

So guess this should work:

```
public function list_people() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = array('order' => array('People.id DESC'),'limit' => 16,'order' => 'People.id DESC');
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('People');
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did that, but now I get "Indirect modification of overloaded property InfoController::$Paginator has no effect"

I tried to solve it using the documentation, doing "$this->Paginator = array();" but nothing...

Answer (score 4):

here is how I am doing it in cake 2.x

first of all be sure to include paginator component and helper in your controller, like

```
$public $components = array(
  'Paginator'
);

$public $helpers = array(
  'Paginator'
);
```

then in your action

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.status' => 1
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Post.id',
        'Post.title',
        'Post.created'
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'Post.created' => 'DESC'
    ),
    'limit' => 10
);

$this->Paginator->settings = $options;
$posts = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in CakePHP 4.x.  There is no Paginator object.  I tried something like $posts = $this->paginate('Post',$options);  But it did not work.